# How to search dictionary using a list that I have significantly modified?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, biopython

I have one csv file that is in the format like so:

```
chr summit

chr1    10261297

chr1    10860583

chr1    10860583

chr1    11693687

chr1    11774340

chr1    NA
```

Where the first column is chromosomes and the second is where the peak is.

I have a FASTA file that has a bunch of entries that follow this format:

```
chr1:37942-38092
CGACACGTGGTGATATTGTAGTGGCTGTCTACTGCACTTTTTGGTATATCTCAAGTTGCTTCTCTACGAGCCAGAAGCTTCAATGTGAAGCTCACGTAGGTAAAAGTGAGTGTGGTGGTCCACAATTGCTTACGTGTAAACGATTATTGG
```

The header part has the chromosome as well as a point that is 75 down from the peak and 75 up from the peak. I am trying to write a program that will allow me to use that first file to search through the second to find if these values match. I managed to write a code that allows me to change the FASTA file into a dictionary so that the key is the first line ("chr1:37942-38092" from the example) and the DNA sequence is the value. Then I modified the first file so that all "NA" values are changed to 0, changed it so that everything becomes an int, subtracted 75 from that value, then changed the format so that it looks more like the key of the FASTA file dictionary. My hope is to then use the newly modified list to search through the keys for matches.

So far my code is:

```
from Bio import SeqIO
import csv
FASTA_dict = SeqIO.to_dict(SeqIO.parse("FASTA_dict_source.fasta", "fasta"))
with open('chr_and_summits.csv', 'rb') as infile:
next(infile) #gets rid of header line
reader = csv.reader(infile)
for row in reader:
    for i,value in enumerate(row):
        row[i] = value.replace('NA','0')    
    row[1]=int(row[1])
    row[1]=row[1]-75
    row[1]=str(row[1])
    row_id=row[0]+':'+row[1]
```

However, now I am stuck. I think I'm supposed to make it so that the new format I've made the list into becomes a new file and then use that file to search the keys, but I am not sure how to do this. I tried looking it up, but couldn't find anything. I am new to python and biopython and don't really know what I am doing, so any help would be appreciated! Thank you!!

Comment: one error is next(infile) , it should be infile.next()

Comment: @PadraicCunningham They are both similar.

Comment: @aIKid, I have never seen next(infile) being used.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham They both call the same method of the file instance, `file.next`.

Comment: How do you store the values of the file chr_and_summits.csv? If you don't store them at some point of the loop you lose everything. I would store it in a list and then use this list to check if it is in the file FASTA_dict_source.fasta (in the example you paste there is no `>`, so it is not a fasta file)

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use an intermediary file for the CSV unless it is a big file. You can generate a list with keys and search the FASTA file.

```
from Bio import SeqIO
import csv 


def csv_to_dict(csv_file):
    """Return a list with the keys to search the SeqIO.dict."""

    peaks_keys = []

    with open(csv_file, 'rb') as infile:
        reader = csv.reader(infile)
        next(reader, None)  # gets rid of header line

        for row in reader:
            # Instead of using enumerate python has nice list comprehension
            # syntax.
            row = [0 if col == "NA" else col for col in row]

            # This line parses the csv format into the same format you used
            # in the FASTA file headers.
            # max(...) ensures no value drop below 0.
            new_key = "{0}:{1}-{2}".format(
                row[0], max(int(row[1]) - 75, 0), int(row[1]) + 75) 

            peaks_keys.append(new_key)

     return peaks_keys

peaks = csv_to_dict("sample.csv")

# Now to search in the FASTA dict:
FASTA_dict = SeqIO.to_dict(SeqIO.parse("sample.fasta", "fasta"))

for peak in peaks:
    seq = FASTA_dict.get(peak)

    if seq:
        # If the row in the CSV has it match in the FASTA file,
        # seq contains the SeqRecord you can play with.
        print seq
```

---

I'm assuming that your CSV file is properly formated:

```
chr,summit
chr1,10261297
chr1,10860583
chr1,10860583
chr1,11693687
chr1,11774340
chr1,NA
```

And the FASTA file is also loadable (">" before heading):

```
>chr1:10860508-10860658
CGACACGTGGTGATATTGTAGTGGCTGTCTACTGCACTTTTTGGTATATCTCAAGTTGCTTCTCTACGAGCCAGAAGCTTCAATGTGAAGCTCACGTAGGTAAAAGTGAGTGTGGTGGTCCACAATTGCTTACGTGTAAACGATTATTGG
```